# ActiveRecord valid? method returning true even with errors present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a head scratcher here that I'm sure is simple and I'm just overlooking. Consider the following model:

```
class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :flaggable, polymorphic: true

  validates :reason, presence: true
  validates :flaggable_id, presence: true
  validates :flaggable_type, presence: true

  before_create :allow_unique_only

private
  def allow_unique_only
    errors.add(:base, "You have already flagged this.") if self.user.flagged?(self.flaggable)

    Rails.logger.debug("Errors: #{errors.full_messages}")
    Rails.logger.debug("Valid: #{valid?}")
  end
end
```

Pretty straightforward. Except when I execute this, it adds the error to base and gives me the error output in the console as it should, however it also states the object is valid.

`Errors: ["You have already flagged this."]
Valid: true`

And it saves! What gives?

**EDIT:** I know I can make it work by adding something like `errors.empty?` at the end of that method, I'm just trying to understand *why* it's being considered valid by ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding the method as a validator, once the validator is done, you can check `valid?`

Remove the before_create and then add:

```
validate :allow_unique_only
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: Rails docs say "Valid? Runs all the validations within the specified context. Returns true if no errors are found, false otherwise."

how its saying valid when errors are present?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question of *why* this happens (because it is surprising to me, as well), I looked at the source code. In version 4.8.2 (the one I'm using which also exhibits this behavior), the definition of `ActiveModel#valid?` **clears existing errors** and then runs the "real" validations.

```rb
def valid?(context = nil)
  current_context, self.validation_context = validation_context, context
  errors.clear
  run_validations!
ensure
  self.validation_context = current_context
end
```

I tried tracking down the history of this behavior, but it hasn't been changed in 12 years and was apparently part of a project migration from SVN; the old SVN repo wouldn't load for me, so the original "why" might be lost to the sands of time.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8ee716182df410052707c3d1eabf8bfd8e0e1c5e/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L335-L343